# CI/CD set up for one ADF environment having multiple project pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, cicd, repo

I have one ADF environment where I developed and tested Pipelines for 2 separate Projects.
Branch is same as well for the ADF pipelines. Now I am a stage of setting up CI/CD pipelines for both projects separately.

**How should I proceed as I am doing this first time?
I just realized that the "adf_publish" branch will be having code for both Projects in one.** This is the first time I have to create CI/CD for ADF and I am on a time crunch.

[image]

Comment: Hi, are you using ADF pipelines? Do you mean you want to move Data Factory pipelines for multiple projects from one environment to another ? Have you read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery)?

Comment: Hi Dou - Yes , I want to set up CI/CD for two project pipelines sitting under same Data Factory (Same Repo). This CI/CD for both projects would eventually move code to higher env like UAT,PROD. Hope the question is clear now. Can you advise if this is possible from one same ADF? Yes I saw that doc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two folders in master branch:
one contains pipeline fully developed and tested and other one for in progress pipelines. However, as you correctly pointed out, adf_publish branch will contain the json code for the pipelines in both the folders.

I would recommend you segregate the in-progress pipelines and keep it in a local branch and do not merge until it's tested .

Download the support files of all pipelines under test folder and then delete them from master branch.

Create a new local branch and go to the github repo and upload the pipeline.json files. After fully tested, merge it with the master branch.

Create CICD pipeline for migrating the code in master branch to next environment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery

Comment: Thanks AnnuKumari for responding. I have few questions & would like give more clairy as well :  A) Pipelines in both folders are tested and they are both for different Project but are under same Repository in Devops , even if I remove any one of these pipeline folder and put it in other branch e.g local , will that not create similar problem for me when I would need CI/CD pipelines for both projects running & working live for higher environments ? Sorry , but I feel I am in a trap like situation

Comment: B) Is it an ideal case where we do things like these of developing different project in same ADF env and in same REPO ? I would like to know if this is a best practice that everyone follows. As I feel there is no workaround of making CI/CD work for both projects on the same time.